# Should I replace my question code, or add updated code as an Update after making progress towards my solution?

Tags: discussion

I have made progress in getting closer to a solution to my [How can I return a jQuery multiselect result as an array and use it as the comparison data in an MVC Razor page table method's @foreach function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674255/how-can-i-return-a-jquery-multiselect-result-as-an-array-and-use-it-as-the-compa) question.  I would like to provide an updated code block of what I now have, but am not sure if I should replace the original code block or add it as part of an Update to my question.  I didn't see anything in the FAQ that would suggest which way I should go, other than for editing purposes.  It is a semi-lengthy code block.

Comment: The rule is that your edit should not invalidate any given answer and you shouldn't replace the whole question with a different one. So in your case I don't see a problem with replacing the old code with a new one when you don't need the old code in order to understand the question and to be able to answer it. If you need both, then you should provide both versions. Keep in mind that the users here have no idea about your project, your setup etc. so you should provide any information needed to answer the question. Also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example might help too.

Comment: This would make a great [meta-tag:faq] question.

Comment: There is also rule that answers go into answer and not comments... so following rules is not a rule as demonstrated by @Tom :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Actually, I don't think there is any such rule.  There is a rule that comments should not be posted as answers ... but not the reverse.  If there was the reverse rule, then many people would not get any help at all.  (But nice joke ...)

Comment: The current state of your question looks to me as if the code example could still be reduced a bit, but I'm not a Javascript expert, so I may be wrong. Please remember that we want a [stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My comment wasn't a fully-fledged answer (at least not in my point of view), hence just a comment :).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The rule is that your edit should not invalidate any given answer and you should not replace the whole question with a different one.

So in your case I don't see a problem with replacing the old code with a new version, if you don't need the old code in order to understand the question and to be able to answer it. If you need both, then you should provide both versions. Keep in mind that the users here have no idea about your project, your setup etc., so you should provide any information needed to answer the question.

As always make sure to check the guidance provided in [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on posting code; don't just copy your current code, but rather carefully select only that part of the code relevant to the question, which should actually demonstrate the problem.

---

<sub>Original version is mostly copied from [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401272/should-i-replace-my-question-code-or-add-updated-code-as-an-update-after-making?noredirect=1#comment796717_401272) by [Tom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom)</sub>

Comment: @Tom Thanks for the answer.  I'll do my best on the Minimal, Reproducible Example; however in this case it is a .cshtml Razor page with a multiselect list and a db table display, both of which are part of the problem, so I don't think I can minimalize it any more.

Comment: @SirAsksaLot Are really ALL columns necessary to reproduce your problem? I'm sure you could shrink that down. When I looked at your question, I immediately decided: I'm not going to read this! I could imagine, many others will have similar feelings. It's very important to provide minimal examples. For readability, and - very nice side effect - you often identify the problem yourself, when trying to really reduce/isolate it.

Comment: @Tom  You're right.  Now that I think about it, I could pair it all down to just the Circuit (key) column.  Once that is working, the following details should be available from the record retrieved.  Thanks again.